# Batch replace (rename) parts of filename

Tags: batch-file

I would like to replace parts of filenames in a directory. In my case the first 4 letters "test".

Filenames
test.exe
test.ini
test_1zb.exe
test_1zb.ini
test_title_1zb.exe
test_title_1zb.ini

I would like to replace "test" with something else.

What is the best solution to do that?

Thanks

Comment: download total commander evaluation copy or buy full and use its built-in multi-renaming tool

Comment: On cmd line and with text to replace in front: `for /f "tokens=1* delims=t" %a in ('dir /B test*') do ren test%b other%b` this uses the last char of `test` to split the name (leading delims are ignored) In a batch file double the percent signs.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a `for` loop to do this just like below:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%I in (string_you_want_to_rename*) do (set "filename=%%~nxI" & ren !filename! OtherString!filename:~x!)
```

where:

- `string_you_want_to_rename` is the string that will be replaced,
- `OtherString` is the string that you would like to replace
- `x` in `!filename:~x!` is the number of characters (including spaces) that `string_you_want_to_rename` has.

Hope this helps!